# Android app retrieve data from server, save in database and display to user

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, android-contentresolver, kotlin-coroutines

I'm rewriting an app that involves retrieving data from a server via REST, saving that to the database on each Android device, and then displaying that data to the user.  The data being retrieved from the server has a "since" parameter, so it won't return all data, just data that has changed since the last retrieval.

I have the retrieval from the server working fine, but I'm not sure the best way to save that data to the database, ***then*** show it to the user.  I'm using Kotlin, Retrofit, Room and LiveData.

The code below is a simplified version of what I'm actually doing, but it gets the point across.

MyData.kt (model)

```
@Entity(tableName = "MyTable")
data class MyData(
  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
  @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
  var id Int? = null,

  @SerializedName("message")
  @ColumnInfo(name = "message")
  var message: String? = null
) {
    companion object {
      fun fromContentValues(values: ContentValues): MyData {
        val data = MyData()
        // Do this for id and message
        if (values.containsKey("id") {
          data.id = values.getAsInteger("id")
        }
      }
    }
}
```

DataViewModel.kt

```
class DataViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
  private val repository = DataRepository()

  fun data(since: Long) =
    liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
      val data = repository.getDataFromServer(since)
      emit(data)
    }

  fun saveData(data: List<MyData>) =
    liveData(Dispatchers.Default) {
      val result = repository.saveDataToDatabase(data)
      emit(result)
    }

  fun data() =
    liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
      val data = repository.getDataFromDatabase()
      emit(data)
    }
}
```

DataRepository.kt

```
class DataRepository(application: Application) {

  // I won't add how the Retrofit client is created, it's standard
  private var client = "MyUrlToGetDataFrom"

  private var myDao: MyDao

  init {
    val myDatabase = MyDatabase.getDatabase(application)
    myDao = myDatabase!!.myDao()
  }

  suspend fun getDataFromServer(since: Long): List<MyData> {
    try {
        return client.getData(since)
    } catch (e: Exception) {

    }
  }

  fun getDataFromDatabase(): List<MyData> = myDao.getAll()

  suspend fun insertData(data: List<MyData>) = 
    myDao.insertData(data)
  }
```

MyDao.kt

```
@Dao
interface PostsDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM " + Post.TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + Post.COLUMN_ID + " desc")
    suspend fun getAllData(): List<MyData>

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertData(data: List<MyData>)
}
```

ListActivity.kt

```
private lateinit var mDataViewModel: DataViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceBundle: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceBundle)
  mDataViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, DataViewModelFactory(contentResolver)).get(DataViewModel::class.java)

  getData()
}

private fun getData() {
  mDataViewModel.data(getSince()).observe(this, Observer {
    saveData(it)
  })
}

private fun saveData(data: List<MyData>) {
  mDataViewModel.saveData(data)
  mDataViewModel.data().observe(this, Observer {
    setupRecyclerView(it)
  })
}
```

ListActivity.kt, and possibly the ViewModel and Repository classes where it uses coroutines, are where I'm stuck.  getData() retrieves the data from the server without a problem, but when it comes to saving it in the database, then taking that saved data from the database and displaying it to the user I'm unsure of the approach.  As I mentioned I'm using Room, but Room will not let you access the database on the main thread.

Remember, I have to save in the database first, then retrieve from the database, so I don't want to call `mDataViewModel.data().observe` until after it saves to the database.

What is the proper approach to this?  I've tried doing CoroutineScope on the mDataViewModel.saveData() then `.invokeOnCompletion` to do `mDataViewModel.data().observe`, but it doesn't save to the database.  I'm guessing I'm doing my Coroutines incorrectly, but not sure where exactly.

It will also eventually need to delete and update records from the database.

Comment: I have one confusion. What do you want to do when ListActivity is open. 1. You want to load all the previous data saved in the database, in recyclerview and then make the network call, get a response from the server and save in database. After that show those data too. 2. when ListActivity is open, you want to make network calls first, then save the response in the database and after that load data in recyclerview

Comment: When it's opened, I want it to 1. Make a network call to check for new data.  2. Save that data in the database.  3. Retrieve the data from the database.  4. Display that data in the recyclerview.

Comment: you want to retrieve all data saved in the database or the latest data fetched from the server and saved in the database?

Comment: Latest data from server and data in database at the same time.  That's why the flow I outlined has:  1. Network call.  2. Save data.  3. Retrieve data.  4. Display data.

Comment: If you want to display all data then it is better to load previous data when listactivity open and if new data is fetched from server then load that data. Since you are using livedata so when database change it will observe it.

Comment: How would I go about doing that then?  What would I do in my ListActivity?

Comment: It seems that doing `val myData = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) { emit(myData) }` doesn't work quite so well with Room.

Comment: is your save data method working properly? are you able to save data in room? Why are you using ContentResolver?

Comment: I'm not anymore, I updated the question.  But yes, it is saving it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated Answer

After reading comments and updated question I figured out that you want to fetch a small list of data and store it to database and show all the data stored in the database. If this is what you want, you can perform the following *(omitted DataSouce for brevity)* -

In `PostDao` You can return a `LiveData<List<MyData>>` instead of `List<MyData>` and observe that `LiveData` in the Activity to update the `RecyclerView`. Just make sure you remove the `suspend` keyword as `room` will take care of threading when it returns `LiveData`.

```
@Dao
interface PostsDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM " + Post.TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + Post.COLUMN_ID + " desc")
    fun getAllData(): LiveData<List<MyData>>

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertData(data: List<MyData>)
}
```

In Repository make 2 functions one for fetching remote data and storing it to the database and the other just returns the `LiveData` returned by the `room`. You don't need to make a request to `room` when you insert the remote data, `room` will automatically update you as you are observing a `LiveData` from `room`.

```
class DataRepository(private val dao: PostsDao, private val dto: PostDto) {

    fun getDataFromDatabase() = dao.getAllData()

    suspend fun getDataFromServer(since: Long) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val data = dto.getRemoteData(since)
        saveDataToDatabase(data)
    }

    private suspend fun saveDataToDatabase(data: List<MyData>) = dao.insertData(data)
}
```

Your ViewModel should look like,

```
class DataViewModel(private val repository : DataRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val dataList = repository.getDataFromDatabase()

    fun data(since: Long) = viewModelScope.launch {
       repository.getDataFromServer(since)
    }
}
```

In the Activity make sure you use [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter.html)

```
private lateinit var mDataViewModel: DataViewModel
private lateinit var mAdapter: ListAdapter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceBundle: Bundle?) {
    ...
    mDataViewModel.data(getSince())
    mDataViewModel.dataList.observe(this, Observer(adapter::submitList))
}
```

### Initial Answer

First of all, I would recommend you to look into [Android Architecture Blueprints v2](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples). According to [Android Architecture Blueprints v2](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples) following improvements can be made,

1. `DataRepository` should be **injected** rather than instantiating internally according to the Dependency Inversion principle.
2. You should **decouple** the functions in the `ViewModel`. Instead of returning the `LiveData`, the `data()` function can update an encapsulated `LiveData`. For example,

   ```
   class DataViewModel(private val repository = DataRepository) : ViewModel() {
       private val _dataList = MutableLiveData<List<MyData>>()
       val dataList : LiveData<List<MyData>> = _dataList

       fun data(since: Long) = viewModelScope.launch {
           val list = repository.getData(since)
           _dataList.value = list
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
3. `Repository` should be responsible for fetching data from remote data source and save it to local data source. You should have two data source i.e. `RemoteDataSource` and `LocalDataSource` that should be injected in the Repository. You can also have an abstract `DataSource`. Let's see how can you improve your repository,

   ```
   interface DataSource {
       suspend fun getData(since: Long) : List<MyData>
       suspend fun saveData(list List<MyData>)
       suspend fun delete()
   }

   class RemoteDataSource(dto: PostsDto) : DataSource { ... }
   class LocalDataSource(dao: PostsDao) : DataSource { ... }

   class DataRepository(private val remoteSource: DataSource, private val localSource: DataSource) {
       suspend fun getData(since: Long) : List<MyData> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
           val data = remoteSource.getData(since)
           localSource.delete()
           localSource.save(data)
           return@withContext localSource.getData(since)
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
4. In your `Activity`, you just need to observe the `dataList: LiveData` and submit it's value to `ListAdapter`.

   ```
   private lateinit var mDataViewModel: DataViewModel
   private lateinit var mAdapter: ListAdapter

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceBundle: Bundle?) {
       ...
       mDataViewModel.data(since)
       mDataViewModel.dataList.observe(this, Observer(adapter::submitList))
   }
   ```

Comment: I'm staying away from dependency injection for now, but yeah, point taken.  For the ViewModel though, why use `viewModelScope.launch` versus `liveData(Dispatchers.IO)`?  I was modeling the Retrofit calls after this article:  https://proandroiddev.com/suspend-what-youre-doing-retrofit-has-now-coroutines-support-c65bd09ba067

Comment: You can use liveData{} as well but as I mentioned earlier decoupling is best practice therefore, I used viewModelScope.launch{}. Please have a look at the architecture blueprint link I provided.

Comment: By the way, has my updated answer solved your issue?

Comment: Trying it right now, it's doing everything properly except displaying the items in the recyclerview.  Think something is off with my Adapter because I see the items in the list when submitList is called.  I was using the `setData` and `notifyDataSetChanged()` before, so `mViewDataModel.dataList.observe(this, Observer { mAdapter.setData(it) })`.  Trying to figure out what's wrong now.

Comment: Most often we forget to set layout manager to recyclerView. You can check if you set it already?

Comment: Nope, I was passing the list of data into the constructor of it and using that list in the `onBindViewHolder` function to get the item based on the position (`setData` was "replacing" that list before).  I removed it from the constructor and used the `getItem` method from the ListAdapter.  Works like a charm.  Thanks!